# In Gitlab - How can I clone all the repos under a certain organization?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to clone all the repos under a certain organization called `orgA`. They have over 100+ repos with groups, subgroups etc.

I'm trying to use GitLab's CLI tool to clone all the repos, but the `glab clone` command is for a single group within the org. Not the entire org. So the following doesn't do the job:
`glab repo clone -g <group-id> -p --paginate`

I do not wish to use a thirdparty tool to do this, only `curl` or `glab`

How can I simply clone an entire org?

Thanks

Comment: `How can I simply clone an entire org?` 1. Get all repositories. 2. For each repository 3. Clone 4. goto step 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be simple with an in liner shell script:

```bash
glab api /groups | jq ".[].id" | xargs -I {} glab repo clone -g {} -p --paginate
```

1. The `glab api /groups` makes an authenticate request to [Gitlab's groups API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html) to get all the groups related to an org.
2. We pipe the json response to `jq` to extract the ids of those groups.
3. Lastly, we execute `glab repo clone` command for each of those groups ids using `xargs`